# Highcharts: Make scrollbar only cover the plot area

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

Here's a fiddle of a sample chart, based on the scrollbar tutorial on [highcharts' docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/scrollbar) here: https://jsfiddle.net/zao68u2k/1/
The only changes I made to the default demo were to remove the mask via:

```
scrollablePlotArea: {
  opacity: 1,
}
```

Now that the mask is gone, it does not make sense for the scrollbar to take up the entire width of the chart. I would like to shorten the scrollbar so that it is only the width of the plot itself and does not include the axis, as I have mocked up in the picture. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case instead of `chart.scrollablePlotArea` you should use the `xAxis.scrollbar` property with `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`:

```
xAxis: {
    min: Date.UTC(2023, 6, 1),
    max: Date.UTC(2023, 6, 1, 3),
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    }
}
```

However, this is a functionality offered by Stock, so it is necessary to have a license for this product and import the appropriate library in the project:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rvm1s67w/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.scrollbar